# list indices must be integers or slices when appending a dict to a serializer in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an already created serializer object, I am trying to add a new object to the serializer but I keep getting the error

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am not able to trace where I am going wrong with the creation of the new object. Here is my code below and more explanations.

```
class ClusterFunctionView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = FunctionListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       //returns serializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        cluster = Cluster.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, id=self.kwargs["cluster_id"]).first()
        schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(clusters__in=[cluster]).values().first() # I am getting the new object here
        print('schedule', type(schedule)) # I checked the type, it is a dict
        response.data['schedule'] = schedule # doesn't seem to be appending to the existing serializer.
        return response
```

The following is an example of the output of the schedule object, I printed using print('schedule', schedule):

```
schedule {'id': 7, 'user_id': 3, 'creation_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25, 15, 44, 39, 875485), 'name': 'mandard_1', 'is_active': True, 'comment': 'extract mardard premier batch', 'cron_expression': '@once'}
```

A sample of the existing serializer on which I should add the above object is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "function": "connections",
        "max_concurrency": 1,
        "mandatory_params": {},
        "public_params": {
            "cluster": {
                "account": true,
                "max_pages": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "default": 100
                },
                "profiles_per_page": {
                    "max": 25,
                    "default": 25
                }
            }
        },
        "params": {
            "max_pages": 100,
            "account_function": "user_account",
            "alchemy_directory": "connections",
            "unique_result_obj_attribute": "connection_id"
        }
    }

]
```

I am expecting a serializer with a schedules object, a result like :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "function": "connections",
        "max_concurrency": 1,
        "mandatory_params": {},
        "public_params": {
            "cluster": {
                "account": true,
                "max_pages": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "default": 100
                },
                "profiles_per_page": {
                    "max": 25,
                    "default": 25
                }
            }
        },
        "params": {
            "max_pages": 100,
            "account_function": "user_account",
            "alchemy_directory": "connections",
            "unique_result_obj_attribute": "connection_id"
        }
    },
    "schedule": {} # this should be added as a result
]
```

What could the problem be, and what solution could I undertake? Thanks

Comment: can you provide models and serializers?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the question, realizing it was a small mistake that I did.

In the `def list` function,
This line was the one causing the error :

```
response.data['schedule'] = schedule
```

I realised that the serializer produced was of a `list` result, and I was initially trying to append the `schedule : {}`, directly into a list, hence the error. It should be appended into the first object. Hence I needed to access the object in the list using index, so changing it to below solved the problem:

```
response.data[0]['schedule'] = schedule
```